# Is it possible to set precision for Set<Double>.contains()?

Tags: java, set, double, precision

Let's say we have an implementation of `Set<Double>`. It contains the following values: `[2.0, 5.0, 7.0]`.

`contains(2.0001d)` in this case returns `false` because `double` values are compared by exact match.

Is it possible to set some double precision for `boolean contains(Object o)` method?

If it is not possible what workaround can you suggest except storing values in a sequential collection, iterating through it and comparing each value?

Comment: What kind of `Set` implementation are you using?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I'm using `HashSet`.

Comment: And what would be your precision?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Just theoretically I want to have an option to set any precision for `Set<Double>.contains()`

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set.contains` has a precise definition based upon equality:

> More formally, returns `true` if and only if this set contains an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

It would violate the contract of the method of it used anything other than equality. And equality has a precise definition which says that it must be transitive (amongst other properties). An equality method which uses a tolerance is not transitive.

As such, there is no way for `Set.contains` to allow a tolerance.

However, this is not to say that you shouldn't ever check to see if a set contains a value within a tolerance of some value - just don't try to overload the concept of `contains` to do it.

For example, you could have a method which takes a `NavigableSet` (for example a `TreeSet`), and use its [`subSet` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#subSet-E-boolean-E-boolean-):

```
static boolean containsApprox(NavigableSet<Double> set, double target, double eps) {
  return !set.subSet(target - eps, true, target + eps, true).isEmpty();
}
```

This just requests the portion of the set which runs from `target-eps` to `target+eps` (inclusive, as indicated by the `true` parameters). If this is non-empty, there is a value in the set within `eps` of the `target`.

This is clearly a separate concept from the standard `Set.contains`, so it is fine for this to do a contains check which doesn't share the same properties.

You can't do the same `subSet` trick with a `HashMap` because it is an unordered map - there is no efficient way to extract the values in a given range. You would have to iterate the entire set, as in [Sun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127610/3788176), looking for a matching value.

Comment: I like the subset idea which certainly works better than my suggestion.

Comment: @assylias very much agreed, this is extremely nice!

Answer (score 3):

May be you can use `anyMatch`, for example, compared based on the first two digit after `.`:

```
Set<Double> set = Set.of(2.0, 5.0, 7.0);

Double compared = 2.0001d;

System.out.println(
        set.stream().anyMatch(aDouble -> 
                Math.floor(aDouble * 100) / 100 == Math.floor(compared * 100) / 100
));
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see three options:

- round the numbers before adding them to the set
- write a `double` wrapper class and redefine the equals method
- use a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator

Note that the last two options may or may not be satisfactory in the sense that the order in which you populate the set has an impact on which elements are retained. For example if you set the precision to 0.01 and add 0.01 then 0.011 then 0.02, you will have two elements in the set (0.01 and 0.02). If you add 0.011 then 0.01 then 0.02, you will only have one element: 0.011. I don't know if that's a problem for your use case.

The last option could look like this:

```
static Set<Double> setWithPrecision(double epsilon) {
  return new TreeSet<> ((d1, d2) -> {
    if (d1 <= d2 - epsilon) return -1;
    if (d1 >= d2 + epsilon) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Example use:

```
Set<Double> set = setWithPrecision(0.01);
set.add(0d);
set.add(0.00001d);
set.add(0.01d);
set.add(0.02d);

System.out.println(set); // [0.0, 0.01, 0.02]
```

Comment: Nice. But he could simply set the precision of the passed in Double number much easier by using a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Yes sure, or simply round the doubles before adding them to the set - I've added that option.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to provide him with the rounding process using BigDecimal.

Comment: No no no no no. Equals and compare methods which have a tolerance are not transitive, and so violate the contracts of those methods (and how would you implement `hashCode` to be consistent with equals, other than making it return a fixed value). Please do not advocate either 2 or 3 as solutions, this will lead to very surprising bugs. And 1 isn't transitive either.

Comment: @AndyTurner hmm you make a very valid point about this to be honest.

Comment: @AndyTurner Agreed. I've added a note. I think option 1 is ok in the sense that you hold a "canonical" representation of each value in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your `HashSet#contains` calling point, is within a method that somehow receives a `Double` from somewhere, you could simply go ahead and set the precision of the `Double`. While `Double` does not offer an out of the box way of rounding a `Double` object you could very well create a rounding helper that will accept the precision you would like to achieve and return the rounded number.

For example:

```
public static Double roundToPrecision(Double number, int precision) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(number)
        .setScale(precision, RoundingMode.DOWN)
        .doubleValue();
}
```

Passing in `2.0001d` will effectively result in this getting round to `2.0`.